# PHPUnit unable to find GearmanClient

Tags: php, macos, phpunit, command-line-interface

I am running phpunit locally on OSX with 1 test to see if I get a response back from Gearman.  I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'GearmanClient' not found
```

Here is the code:

```
class GearmanTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testGearmanClient() {
        $gmc = new GearmanClient();
        $gmc->addServer('localhost');
    }
}
```

The strange thing is that if I don't try to run it through phpunit, it works just fine.  Call me crazy, but aren't they both simple cli processes?  I did notice a difference in the include_path found, but when I force the include path to be the same, there is no effect.

Please help.

Comment: What do you do if you "don't run it through phpunit"? Do you also use the command line? If you use a web page, this would explain it because PHP for CLI usually uses a different configuration file which might miss the Gearman extension.

Comment: I just have a simple script that looks like this:
        <?php $gmc = new GearmanClient(); $gmc->addServer('localhost'); ?> and I run it from the command line.  That is why it seems so weird to me.

Comment: You are not loading the class that includes the code for GearmanClient().  You either need to include it, or configure an autoloader for PHPUnit.

Comment: I'm sure that is the case, but why does it work just fine when I run a simple cli script without any kind of autoloading.  Besides, I did a search of my system to see if I could explicitly load a particular file and never found one.  This is a pecl extension, so it should just be available anyways.

Answer (score 1):

If the class `GearmanClient` can't be found (as described in your example), then that's because the extension is not installed.

Try running

```
$ php -i | grep gearman
```

If the extension were installed, then the above command would output something like

```
Additional .ini files parsed => /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/conf.d/ext-gearman.ini,
gearman
gearman support => enabled
libgearman version => 1.1.12
e2 => feature/gearman-manager
_SERVER["e2"] => feature/gearman-manager
```

You can probably find something here on Stackoverflow how to install it on your system.

If you're on OS X, you probably want to use http://brew.sh for installing packages, and here's a great post about installing PHP with Homebrew on OS X:

- http://justinhileman.info/article/reinstalling-php-on-mac-os-x/

Once you got PHP installed, for example, PHP5.6, it's as easy as running

```
$ brew install gearman
```